# (void) vs void as the return type of a function in C

Tags: c

I'm maintaining an application that incorporates C++, C and a few python files; and all executables are build using CMake.

I noticed a few functions that are using the (void) cast.

Example:

```
main.c:

   typedef void CxType;

   int foo(CxType *, const char *, const char *, int , int *);

// c is a template 
// QString &s;
// QMapData::Node *e;
// QScopedPointer<QDataStreamPrivate> d;
// v is another template

   #define foo2(c,s,e,d,v) foo(c,s,e,d,v)
 
   static void some_function( void )
   {

     (void) foo(param1,param2,...);

   }
```

According to the O'Reilly "C Pocket reference"; (void) can be used to explicitly discard the value of an expression in C; For example:  (void)printf("An example.")

Why use (void) foo(param1,param2,...); instead of simply foo(param1,param2,...);?

Comment: It should be noted -- despite the title of this question `(void)` is **not** the "return type of a function" in this code.

Comment: If the function was declared as `[[nodiscard]]` the compiler will continue to warn you about the unused return value. In some specific cases where the return value isn't important you want remove the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast to void is there to suppress a compiler warning about unused return value.

// at least that was most probably the intention of the genius that came up with the cast.

Comment: Also, if you return a tuple from C++ function and do not need to use all returned values, you can use `std::ignore` with `std::tie` for it

Comment: I remember lots of compiler warnings about unused _variable(s)_, but never one for unused _return value_.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would only cast an expression to `void` in one of two cases.

First, if a function takes a parameter that you know isn't being used but the parameter can't be removed because the function in question is being used as a callback.

Second, if you're calling a function that has an compiler-specific attribute that causes it to warn if the function's return value isn't used, but you know you don't need to read it.

Neither of these cases apply to the above code, so the cast isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

I admit to using the `(void) foo()` cast style myself; the rationale is to indicate that I know the function returns a value, which I'm deliberately ignoring. That is, it is for the reader (e.g., my future self) rather than to suppress compiler warnings, since popular C compilers do not warn about this (except perhaps with non-standard annotations on specific functions).

Comment: (Note that several other languages don't allow implicitly ignoring return values at all, so you have to do something like `_ = foo()` instead. I view this `(void)` cast as the C equivalent of that, but it just happens to be optional.)